# smooth animation only in firefox 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, smoothing

It seems that the following setup on jsfiddle only runs smooth in firefox 4.
http://jsfiddle.net/ynytc/39/

Im wondering why? 
I thought maybe because of the hardware acceleration in firefox 4,
but without it still runs smooth.

So maybe someone knows why?

edit: compared to chrome,safari,ie8

Comment: Actually it is smoother even in firefox 3.6 :)

Comment: i meant compared to chrome or safari its much smoother in firefox 4, at least on my computers

Comment: I meant the same, however the number 4 is not the key but the word Firefox. Even in FF 3.6 it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're animating over a 10 second period a change in size of only 20 pixels. That means that there's going to be only one integral dimension change every 1/2 second, which is exactly what I see in Chrome. The size of the image can't be set to fractions of a pixel (in all browsers). Firefox 4 seems to allow that, however; that's the only thing I can imagine anyway.

If you change your fiddle [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ38y/) you'll see that Chrome is running the animation as fast as you could want it to, but the image only shifts when there's a whole integer change in the property value (width and height).

Comment: Yeah it seems that firefox is doing some linear interpolation for the pixels while other browsers are not.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting side effect that I hadn't encountered before.

It seems that other browsers can't apply subpixel scaling, so you only have 20 pixels to spread in 10 seconds, coming to a glorius 2 frames per second. The workaround for this would be to apply CSS transitions (if you don't need to support IE).

See example with CSS transitions here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nKfdB/